# embedded responsive page in iframe doesn't render correctly

Tags: css, responsive-design

The main page embeds the responsive mobile page which is developed with JQUERY SUPERSLIDES plugin. The mobile page looks fine if it is loaded directly on the IPHONE with safari. However, it doesn't render as expected on IPHONE(as you can see from the 2nd screenshot below, only part of the image is visible) when it is embedded to the iframe.

main.html

```
    <iframe id="ifrmadcontainer" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"     style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="touch.html">
    </iframe>
```

touch.html is in http://jsfiddle.net/w1vcrLy8/

How it looks on Desktop Safari and Chrome:

[image]

How it looks on IPhone Safari:

[image]

Comment: Your JSFiddle is broken, add the external resources. And I suppose you use media queries based on device-with. So if this is it, then that does not handle iframe with smaller with than the device.

Comment: i can open JSFiddle without any problem. I will try to use media queries

Comment: JSFiddle is useless if we cannot see and test the code. Here we need at least the CSS.
Here are all missing resources:
css/normalize.css
css/superslides.css
css/layout.css
images/IMG_0410.JPG
images/IMG_0411.JPG
images/IMG_0412.JPG
javascripts/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js
javascripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js
javascripts/jquery.animate-enhanced.min.js
javascripts/hammer.min.js
javascripts/jquery.superslides.js
css/normalize.css
css/superslides.css
css/layout.css

Answer (score 0):

Is the meta device-with present on both inside the iframe and outside on the page that embed it?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```